# How do I assign a matrix of data as a label to each input image in my dataset using PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, pytorch

I want to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) in PyTorch to predict frequency spectrum data related to an input image. Rather than assigning one label to each image (Dog, Cat, Car, Airplane, etc.), I would like to assign a matrix of labels (one label per frequency) to each image. In PyTorch, how do I assign a matrix of data as a label to each input image in my dataset? I have been trying to do this using ImageFolder. Thanks!

Comment: This question is only about programming, so it is off-topic here. It should be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageFolder dataset expects a specific structure that only handles one class label and thus is probably not ideal for your needs.

If you look at the [DatasetFolder Class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/folder.html#DatasetFolder) which is the parent class of ImageFolder, notice the `__getitem__` method which takes an index and returns the sample and target. One thing you could do is change the `samples` attribute of the dataloader such that it returns your own path and labels tuple for each index.

Alternatively you can make your own Dataset Class, which inherits from`torch.utils.data.Dataset` and has a `__getitem__` and `__len__` method.